# how select from table where datetime=date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i have `payment` table and one of columns is `p_craetedate` type of `p_createdate` is `DateTime`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Payments](
    [p_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(100000,1) NOT NULL,
    [p_amount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [p_createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [p_creditor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_debtor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_type] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Payments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED )
```

i want get rows that created at '2013-07-16'

Comment: Version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DATE` datatype present in SQL Server **2008** and newer:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.tbl_Payments
WHERE CAST(p_createddate AS DATE) = '20130716'
```

The `DATE` datatype contains only the date - no time portion - therefore comparing to `20130716` in the ISO-8601 format (which works for any language/regional settings of your SQL Server) will give you all the rows that where created on the 16th of July, 2013 - no matter what time of day.

Comment: Even though casting as `DATE` is sargable I still prefer the range seek as [better cardinality estimates](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 1):

You can use queries from some previous answer, but read about `sargable` first.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Payments
WHERE p_createdate >= '20130716'
    AND p_createdate < '20130717'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (list of fields)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE dateValue >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,'2013-07-16 00:00'), 0) 
AND dateValue < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,'2013-07-17 00:00'), 1)
```

Comment: Also `select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,'2013-07-17 00:00'), 1)` is the 18th. I don't see why you are using `DATEADD` at all here. Just the literal constant as in Hamlet's answer would work fine.